# AddEvent Listener error "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" fix

Tags: javascript

I am getting this `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

What I am trying to do is do a mouseover effect using javascript

HTML

```
 <div class="background"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.background{
    background:var(--light--colour);
    height:88.4vh;
}

@keyframes animateBack {
    0%{
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }

    50%{
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

JS

```
let background = document.querySelector(".background")

background.addEventListener('mouseover', event =>{
    event.target.style.background = "linear-gradient(-45deg,#012326,#1FBFA2,#0FF29F,#F2CE16,#D98E04)";
    event.target.style.backgroundSize = "2000% 2000%";
    event.target.style.animation = "animateBack 15s ease infinite";
    
})
```

I attached the error to the question

[image: uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')]

[image]

Comment: it did thank you, I always forget to defer my script file when putting the script file in the header

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sheldon Resume</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Reference/css/main.css">

    <script src="/Reference/js/main.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

I did not defer the js script file in the head of the HTML